# Autorun Gulp task 'watch' on Webstorm launch

Tags: gulp, webstorm

Is there a way to run a Gulp task on Webstorm launch?

Tried looking through webstorm settings but don't see anything, also Gulp integration is brand new to Webstorm 9.

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {

    gulp.watch(paths.watch.css, function(){ compileLESS(paths.src.css, paths.dest.css, {name: 'Style'}) });
    gulp.watch(paths.watch.cssBootstrap, function(){ compileLESS(paths.src.cssBootstrap ,paths.dest.cssBootstrap, {suffix: '.min', name: 'Bootstrap'}) });

    gulp.watch(paths.watch.scripts, ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch(paths.watch.libraries, ['libraries']);

});
```

Just want a way to run **Gulp** ***'watch'*** (if the project has gulp and a task called watch) when ever i start **Webstorm**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No:( WebStorm (as well as other JetBrains IDEs) doesn't support 'on launch' actions - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11818#comment=27-787220

Comment: Hope they support it soon :) Can count how many times I forget to start watch task everyday!

Answer (score 11):

As of WebStorm 11, this is possible.

1. Settings > Tools > Startup Tasks
2. Hit the green plus icon to `Add New Configuration`
3. Choose `Gulp.js`
4. Choose your tasks that you want to run from the `Tasks:` dropdown

Done!

Comment: Indeed, this is the ticket in 2015/16

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is set your gulp task (which sets up the watchers) as a 'before launch' task of your main configuration.

Works great for me. I need to start my server before I can start developing, and when I do, I know this will start my watchers and do any necessary processing for the first time.

Comment: But that will run each time you restart your server which is a little annoying.