# Is there a way automatically start default Gulp task when I open project in Web- or PhpStorm?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

Every time I open my project I have to start default Gulp task manually(to run watchers, browserSync, etc.). Is there a way to automatically launch default Gulp task once project is opened in Web- or PhpStorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was writing my question I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33555777/6693304):

1. Settings > Tools > Startup Tasks
2. Hit the green plus icon to `Add New Configuration`
3. Choose `Gulp.js`
4. Choose your tasks that you want to run from the `Tasks:` dropdown